# Varnish often crashes

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

Varnish version: 4.0.2

I can observe that varnish crashes frequently, error msg:

> Child (2094) died signal=6
>   Child (2094) Panic message:
>                                                                Assert error in vbf_fetch_thread(), cache/cache_fetch.c line 842:
>                                                                  Condition(uu == bo->fetch_obj->len) not true....

Is that problem with config or a varnish bug?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a VERY old Varnish version, and that's related with an [old bug](https://varnish-cache.org/trac/ticket/1596).